# Splitting $3$ boys and $7$ girls into 3 groups with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> There are $ 3 $ boys and $ 7 $ girls. How many ways can we divide them
>   into three unlabeled groups such that each group has a boy, two groups have
>   three people, and the third group has four people?

I think that the answer is $\frac{3!\times \binom{7}{2} \times \binom{5}{2}}{2}=630$, but other people said that it is $\frac{3\times \binom{7}{2} \times \binom{5}{2}}{3}=210$.

Edit: I did wrote something incorrect.

Comment: Why are you dividing by $2$ exactly?

Comment: Are the groups labeled?  Specifically:  if we switch the two smaller groups, do we get a new arrangement or not?

Comment: ${7\choose2}\times{5\choose2}=210$,, so your arithmetic is wrong in both cases.

Comment: @lulu Labelled? These are groups of individuals - surely we can assume they are distinguishable. There is no suggestion that the groups are ordered.

Comment: @almagest Ordered then.  As I specified, my question was "are the two arrangements $(b_1,g_1,g_2), (b_2,g_3,g_4), (b_3, g_5, g_6, g_7)$ and  $(b_2,g_3,g_4),(b_1,g_1,g_2),  (b_3, g_5, g_6, g_7)$ different or not?"  As others have asked about division by $2$, I think it's fair to say that the point is not obvious.

Comment: @adola Those are separate cases, because the boys are different.

Comment: In any case, neither $315$ nor $210$ make sense as answers.  I can understand $1260$ if the groups are ordered and half that, or $630$, if they are not.

Comment: @lulu I agree that only 630 or 1260 could be correct. If you correct the OP's multiplication those answers are 630 (the OP's choice) and 420 - which must be wrong.

Comment: @MatthewDaly They are the same group but counted differently (because group b and group c can be switch).

Comment: The answer is definitely not $3!\times \binom{7}{2} \times \binom{5}{2}=630$ because $3!\times \binom{7}{2} \times \binom{5}{2}=1260$

Answer (score 4):

You're just identifying which of the girls go along with each boy.

So there are 3 ways to choose which of the boys is in the bigger group, and then $\binom73$ ways to choose whose his partners are.  Then there are $\binom42$ ways to choose which of the remaining girls goes with the older of the remaining boys.  Thus, the total is $3\cdot\binom73\binom42=3\cdot35\cdot6=630$.

---

The reason we don't need to do any dividing is because every grouping we are making are distinct.  If Adam, Ben, and Carl are the three boys, then putting Ben with Jane and Kim and Carl with Laura and Mary is a different grouping than if put Ben with Laura and Mary and Carl with Jane and Kim.  Each of the three groups CAN be distinguished -- by which boy is in the group -- so there is no need to worry about overcounting.

Answer (score 0):

All $3$ boys have to be in different groups. Then we have $3$ choices which boy is in a group of $4$ and $\binom7{3,2,2}=210$ ways to choose girls for the groups (assuming the groups are unlabelled), for a total of $3\cdot210=630$.

Answer (score 0):

Since groups are unlabeled 3 boys can be distributed only in 1 way and as 7 girls to be distributed as 2,2,3 into groups hence only 2 of the group be treated like identical groups.
= 630
For more similar to this there is question in other forum link is https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/forum/topic/permutations-and-combinations-2/?part=1#postid-73

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since it matters which boy is in the group of four people.

Comment: What is Number of ways 52 playing cards be divided into 4 parts of 15,15,15 and 7 .

Comment: That is not an analogous problem since the groups are distinguished by which boy is in the group with four people.

Comment: In a question it is mentioned that groups are unmarked. Hence 3 boy can be distributed into 3 unmarked groups in 1 way now groups becomes distinct and of which two will be like identical as number of girls will be equal in two of the group.

Comment: The group of four is distinguished by its size.

Comment: That is what I said that once girls are divided into three groups one of the group will be distinct and 2 identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102768/discussion-between-mathsdiscussion-com-and-n-f-taussig).

Comment: What will be the number of ways 3 boys , 1 girl can be distributed  into 3 identical groups ? Will it be 3 or 3.3!

Comment: A better example is the number of distributions of three boys and four girls into three unlabeled groups so that each boy is in a different group and at most two girls are in the same group.  For that question, I get $\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1} = 36$ such distributions (choose which boy is in the group of three people, which two girls are in his group, and which of the remaining girls is in the same group as the younger of the remaining boys).  The numbers are small enough that you can verify my answer by listing all the possibilities.

Comment: I think in your example did you considered girls are 2,1,1 in groups because as per me also once all boys are distributed into identical groups in 1 way girls can be distributed in $(\frac{4!}{2!(1!)^2})(\frac{3!}{2!})=36 $ but if I also consider girls in groups are 2,2,0 then additional $(\frac{4!}{(2!)^2(1!)})(\frac{3!}{2!})=18$ more cases what I am getting. In actual question I got the calculation mistake I made answer will be 630.same I have corrected in answer

Comment: When I woke up this morning, I realized that I had not worded the question in my previous comment correctly (sorry about that).  I did in fact mean the number of distributions of three boys and four girls into three unlabeled groups so that each boy is in a different group, two girls are in one of the groups, and one girl is in each of the others.  That said, I am glad you figured it out.  You are also correct that given the poor wording in my previous comment, there would be $18$ additional cases.

Comment: Thanks for all . Now I have two methods to solve the above questions

Answer (score -1):

Choose 1 boy from 3, the 2 girls from 7 and 2 girls from 5 and then 3 girls from the 3 left.

So, total combinations: $ ^3C_1 \times ^7C_2 \times ^5C_2 =630$